# Handling HID touch events in OSX

Tags: macos, hid, touchscreen

I'm writing a driver to handle touch events from a Planar touch screen (in OSX) using Apple's IOKit tools. The driver is able to receive x and y coordinates, but I'm having trouble figuring out which finger  the coordinates belong to.

In my callback function, I'm querying the most recent value's parent to determine the finger ID, but the value is always the most recent finger – so 3 if there are 3 fingers down, 2 if there are 2 fingers down, etc., etc. Here's what callback looks like:

```
    void touchCallback(void *context, IOReturn result, void *sender, IOHIDValueRef value) {

        IOHIDElementRef element = IOHIDValueGetElement(value);
        IOHIDDeviceRef device = IOHIDElementGetDevice(element);

        IOHIDElementRef parent = IOHIDElementGetParent(element);
        IOHIDElementRef parent2 = IOHIDElementGetParent(parent);
        CFArrayRef parentChildren = IOHIDElementGetChildren(parent2);
        IOHIDValueRef fingerVal;
        IOHIDDeviceGetValue(device, (IOHIDElementRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(parentChildren, 5), &fingerVal);
        long fingerID = IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue(fingerVal);
   }
```

Is there another recommended approach for determining which finger the x and y coordinates belong to?

Similarly, are there any recommended practices for figuring out which finger is being released?

I'm receiving events that indicate a finger has been lifted, but the numbers are inconsistent – sometimes it'll report the same finger ID 2x, other times it won't report anything. Is there a 'frame'-based approach to testing if a fingers is still down?

Thanks++ for any advice!

Comment: I've posted a solution to this problem here. It uses OpenFrameworks to handle the finger events. http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php/topic,13657.msg58322.html#msg58322.

Comment: Please post the solution here as [an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: For now, I'm posting the updated link from user2977925's comment below as a comment on this post for the record, because I've flagged that post for deletion because it's not a valid answer. Updated link: http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/hid-touch-events-on-osx/13657/3